# Grafana: X-Y chart. How to represent data with separate lines for multi-value variable

Tags: postgresql, grafana, grafana-variable

I have chunks of data for each *build* that I want to visualize with Grafana X-Y chart. Let's say (simplified):

| kpi | average_time | build_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Start App | 150 | 870 |
| Stop App | 890 | 870 |

| kpi | average_time | build_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Start App | 140 | 871 |
| Stop App | 860 | 871 |

I used PostgreSQL to show lines for each `kpi` with `build_id` as X and `average_time` as Y

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (kpi, build_id)
       build_id AS BUILD_ID, 
       average_time AS AVERAGE_TIME
       FROM <MY_TABLE> WHERE kpi IN (${kpi});
```

...and `$kpi` is a multi-value variable simply returned by `SELECT kpi FROM <MY_TABLE>;`

When I try to select `Start App` as single `$kpi` value it looks OK
[image]

but if to select both `$kpi` values it looks like two lines (that's what I want) but connected with each other (that's not what I want) with extra line
[image]

So how to display separate lines for each `kpi` (with possibility to set a color for each)?

**UPDATE**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do what you described, but it is possible.

To show charts in different ways, you'll need to present values to panel as they are different series. It is possible to do in three major ways:

1. Query data as it is, and split it on Grafana's side.
2. Query data within single select, but average time for each kpi should be in a separate column.
3. Query data for each `kpi` independently. I believe it is worst case, as you'll need to a separate query, and link every dataset into panel. I will not describe it in detail as it's fairly clear on its own.

###### Way #1

1. Open edit mode of Panel, tab **Transform**.
2. Add **Partition by values**, select `kpi`. As a result data will be split into separate series.
3. Go to panel options and manually add all new series:

   1. XY Chart > Series mapping > Manual
   2. For every series select corresponding field.

###### Way #2

1. Create query pivoting your data, (for example, using one of answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3002499/21363224)), so that it returns columns in the following manner:

- build_id,
- start_app_avg_time,
- stop_app_avg_time,
- *more of average time for **every** kpi*

2. In panel options: XY Chart > Series mapping > Auto
3. Select **X Field** `build_id`. The rest will be selected automatically.

---

Both ways you result for supplied example data would look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I used 1 solution and now I got separate charts for each `kpi`. But there's a one more problem (check Update): instead of `kpi` name for each line in Legend I see just a `Series 1`, `Series 2` labels... I tried to set `${__series.name}` to Standard options -> Display name (as suggested [here](https://community.grafana.com/t/use-query-name-as-display-name-to-label-series-in-graph/61400/2)). But didn't work. Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: @Curiouskoala, to rename series, click on series name (`Series 1` in your example) in Panel options, it will allow to write new name for series.

Comment: The number of Series and names are not constant, but depends on values user selects from drop-down menu (values of multi-value variable `$kpi`), so I cannot set names simply manually - it should be set automatically somehow... Should I create the new question for this issue?

Comment: @Curiouskoala, you need to add series for every possible value of kpi, and name it accordingly (not selected wouldn't be shown at graph automatically, I believe). But generally, it could be easier to go solution #2 in this case.